# Kotlin MutableList.take in place?

Tags: kotlin

I have managed to `removeAll` from a `MutableList` in-place successfully. This call modifies the receiver list to remove all elements matching the given predicate.

I would like to modify the receiver list by keeping only the first `n` elements but I cannot figure out how to do it since `take` and `slice` calls return a new collection.

Is there an in-place version of `take` or `slice` functions on `MutableList`?

An example of how I would like to use the new function: `myList.keepFirst(5)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `keepFirst(n)` and `keepLast(n)`, you can get a [`subList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/sub-list.html), then `clear()` it. This works because `subList` returns a "view" of the list, not a copy.

```
// suppose "l" is a MutableList
// keepFirst(5)
l.subList(5, l.size).clear()
// keepLast(5)
l.subList(0, l.size - 5).clear()
```

Comment: Neat, depending how out of bounds scenarios to be handled , custom error handling may be required.

Comment: Great, thanks! I found another solution that I will post but I like yours better.

Answer (score 1):

Another way this might be achieved:

```
private fun <T> MutableList<T>.keepFirst(n: Int) {
    while (size > n) {
        removeLast()
    }
}
```